# Proving $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges. It's enough to show that the series of partial sums $S_N = \sum\limits_{n=0}^N a_n$ converges. We have
$$s_N = \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
We propose that its limit is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. We have to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $K$ such that $N > K$ implies $|s_N - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} | < \epsilon$. I'm stuck on showing this, however. The set-up is:
\begin{align*}
\left \lvert s_N - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \right \rvert & = \left \lvert \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!} - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \right \rvert \\
& = \left \lvert \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \right \rvert \\
& = \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
As $n \to \infty$, each of these terms go to $0$, so I should be able to pick such a $K$ to make this less than $\epsilon$, but I can't figure out how to solve for it and to "isolate" $n$.

Comment: Can't you use one of the excellent tests for convergence? Ratio, the $\;n\,-$th root...something? BTW, $$\left|s_N-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|=\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|$$ and not what you wrote...

Comment: This was an error on my part, thank you. I don't have access to the convergence tests yet. I need to prove it from the definition that a series converges if and only if its sequence of partial sums converge.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is *by definition* $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{x^n}{n!}$, under the condition that such limit exists. Therefore, you cannot use it as an estimate of the limit to prove the existence of such limit, just like you cannot say that since $L=\frac{L^2-1}3$ has roots $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{13}}2$ the sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2-1}{3}$ converges to one of those.

Comment: This makes sense. I thought I was proposing a guess for the limit and then proving that it actually is the limit. Is there another way to prove convergence? Do I need to show instead that the $S_N$ are bounded and monotonic, hence convergent?

Comment: @StanleySmith I don't think they are monotonic, if $x<0$.

Answer (score 2):

One way to prove it is as follow : $(s_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a non-decreasing sequence therefore it suffices to show that it is bounded above. There exists $C>0$ such that $\frac{|x|^n}{n!}\leqslant\frac{C}{2^n}$, this is because $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}=0$, thus the sequence $\left(\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is bounded. Finally, $$ s_n\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{C}{2^k}\leqslant C $$
and this ends the proof.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This makes a lot of sense. The only remaining question I have is, how do we prove that the sum is non-decreasing? I know that the exponential function is non-decreasing, but does this in any way depend on the sign of $x$?

Comment: It is non-decreasing because $s_n-s_{n-1}=\frac{x^n}{n!}\geqslant 0$ for $x\geqslant 0$ (it suffices to study the case $x\geqslant 0$ because you can deduce from it the absolute convergence of the series for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Observe that if $\left| x \right| \le \left\lfloor {\frac{{N + 2}}{2}} \right\rfloor$,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = N + 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left| x \right|^n }}{{n!}}} & = \frac{{\left| x \right|^{N + 1} }}{{(N + 1)!}}\left( {1 + \frac{{\left| x \right|}}{{N + 2}} + \frac{{\left| x \right|^2 }}{{(N + 1)(N + 3)}} +  \cdots } \right)
\\ &
 \le \frac{{\left| x \right|^{N + 1} }}{{(N + 1)!}}\frac{1}{{1 - \left| x \right|/(N + 2)}} \le 2\frac{{\left| x \right|^{N + 1} }}{{(N + 1)!}}.
\end{align*}
Since
$$
\frac{{\left| x \right|^{N + 1} }}{{(N + 1)!}} \to 0,
$$
for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $K>0$ such that
$$
2\frac{{\left| x \right|^{N + 1} }}{{(N + 1)!}} < \varepsilon 
$$
for all $N>K$. Hence,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = N + 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left| x \right|^n }}{{n!}}}  < \varepsilon 
$$
for all $N> \max (2\left| x \right| - 2,K)$.